# Data brought from mysql displayed in divs now Ordering them How?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say i have the following information displayed in seperate divs brought from mysql from 6 rows

```
<?php
echo "<div id='id'>
echo $row['id'];

echo "<div id='description'>
echo $row['description'];

echo "<div id='price'>
echo $row['price'];

?>
```

Now I need to order them by ID /price so i put them in an array

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $id_array[] = $row['id'];
     $price_array[] = $row['price'];
```

Now i am not sure how to display the ordered items 
Do i do my sql method which is `SELECT*FROM books ORDER BY id DESC`
which i tried and is not working or the php array ksort- which i am not sure how to write.
Also if i have to successfully order the displayed data will have to move from their divs to the appropriate div.

Advance Apologies if this sounds really confusing!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the SQL statement by using

```
ORDER BY id ASC, Price ASC
```

To add this to your array you'd do something along the lines of:

```
$count = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     $array[$count][0] = $row['id'];
     $array[$count][1] = $row['price'];
     $count++;
}
```

Otherwise you can just output the data directly like so:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
     echo $row['id']. " - ".$row['price']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thats right! but now how do i echo it out in <div id='id'> where the information is already contained

Comment: the result will be already sorted after you query with the above query

Comment: I've updated the above with an example of how you would store the information in an array and then you just loop through the array to output your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this,

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id ASC, price ASC
```

Using php and a while loop you could then output the contents, (this is using PDO)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo '<div id="id">' . $row['id'] . '</div>';

    echo '<div id="description">' . $row['description'] . '</div>';

    echo '<div id="price">' . $row['price'] . '</div>';
}
```

Also note that `html` `attributes` are surrounded by double qoutes `"`!

Hope this helps